# JQuery JSON not returning data

Tags: jquery, json, get

I'm trying to get game server data from my other host because my main host doesn't allow server querying. But i'm having problems with json right now..

My code:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input.senddata").click(function() {
            var ipForm = $('input[name="ip_submit"]').val();
            var gameForm = $( 'select[name="game_submit"]' ).val()
            $.getJSON("http://gamepwn.net/serversdotee/add-server.php?json=true",
              {
                ip: ipForm,
                game: gameForm
              },
              function(data) {
                $('.result').html(data);
              });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The data that i want to get back is a simple text for example "Server has been queried"..

Comment: Check in Firefox's Firebug plugin, or in Chrome's Developer tools to see if you're getting any AJAX response back.

Comment: If you want to do cross-domain requests, you need to use a data type of JSONP. And, if you specify a data type of JSONP, the response needs to be valid JSON.

Comment: I do get back a response!
GET http://gamepwn.net/serversdotee/add-server.php?json=true&ip=188.92.161.28%3A27040&game=cs
 
200 OK
  2.07s

Answer (score 2):

Either your "other server" needs to return proper CORS headers, or you need to move to the `JSONP` datatype and modify your "other server" so that it properly returns `JSONP` rather than `JSON`.

JSONP vs JSON:

JSON: `http://gamepwn.net/serversdotee/add-server.php?json=true`

```
{"foo":"bar"}
```

JSONP: `http://gamepwn.net/serversdotee/add-server.php?json=true&callback=??`

```
jQuery_7891469862340189270349182561({"foo":"bar"})
```

Where `jQuery_7891469862340189270349182561` is the value of the callback GET parameter.